# Different builds for JavaScript and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to have 2 builds: for JavaScript (node) and for jasmine-node. And have them selected automatically by Sublime Text based on file extension (or other condition). I have:
**JavaScript.sublime-build**:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

**JasmineNode.sublime-build**:

```
{
  "cmd": ["jasmine-node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^.+\\((.+):([0-9]+)\\)$",
  "selector": "source.spec.js"
}
```

JavaScript build is always used on `.spec.js` files instead of Jasmine and I have to choose Jasmine build manually. How can I make Jasmine build work automatically?

Comment: Make sure that you have the Jasmine syntax selected when you're attempting to build, and that `Tools -> Build System` is set to `Automatic`. Otherwise, @leemour's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21329772/1426065) below should work.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime's [build variants](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#variants) can be used like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "variants": [
        { "cmd": ["jasmine-node", "--noColor", "$file"],
          "file_regex": "^.+\\((.+):([0-9]+)\\)$",
          "name": "Test"
        }
  ]
}
```

And then a variant can be assigned to a hotkey like this:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+f7"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Test"} }
```

But I think there should be a way to select `.spec.js` instead of `.js` in filename for a build.